# Calculate Momentum for Water Bottle

Tags: fluid-dynamics, momentum, simulations, computational-physics

I'm working on a bottle of water. The bottle is moved by the mouse and the water reacts to it. I'm not particularly educated in math and physics. I'm merely a programer. I'm not even sure, if my sine function is correct, to illustrate the water in the bottle.

Here is an hardcoded example of what it should look like with a fixed momentum.

[image: Water Bottle example]

This is what I came up with:

[image: Attempt]
[image: Graph]

Comment: What do you mean by "reacts to mouse movement"?  Does the mouse move the bottle (as a hand would), and then the water inside responds?  Or does the mouse move the water in the bottle --- like stirring it?

Comment: The former, the mouse moves the bottle.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What result are you after? Are you trying to calculate the momentum of sloshing water in a bottle? Also you mention stirring without any description of what you physically mean followed by question marks that aren't questions. Also, do you have pre-described functions for the motion of the fluid? The question and description is very unclear.

Comment: What is the end purpose of your simulation? Surely you are not aiming at a full-scale CFD of sloshing motion of water inside the bottle. If you only want to create an illusion of water reacting to movement of bottle, you make the water surface tilt up towards opposite end when the bottle is accelerated, or may be introduce higher frequency oscillations on the surface when the bottle is being moved, which then slowly die out when the bottle is brought to rest, until water surface becomes flat.

Comment: @Zero that's exactly want I want to do. The function should tilt the water and create two waves. This is working fine with fixed values. I now have problems translating the movement of the mouse into momentum with the right formula. I know the bottle needs mass and I need the velocity of the mouse and somewhere need to put in the time, so the water will eventually come to a stop, if I stopped moving the mouse. I know I can use p = mv somehow, but don't know how to transform it, to my needs.

Comment: ...  I can use the momentum value then for the amplitude, phasesshift and angle of the sine to create the illusion of water movement.

Comment: "I now have problems translating the movement of the mouse into momentum with the right formula..." This question seems appropriate for programmers, and not in this site.